# Git asks password for wrong username whenever I git pull or push

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a repo - let's say it's remote address is https://myself@bitbucket.org/myself/my-repo.git. I am sharing this repo with my colleague - I have granted him admin access to this repo to his account. Let's say his bitbucket account is https://mycolleague@bitbucket.org. He clones the repo. But whenever he tries to push/pull the repo, git asks for the password for my account (https://myself@bitbucket.org) not his account (https://mycolleague@bitbucket.org). How do I change git settings so that git asks for his account (https://mycolleague@bitbucket.org) instead of mine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your colleague cloned  `https://myself@bitbucket.org/myself/my-repo.git` and not `https://mycolleague@bitbucket.org/myself/my-repo.git`.  The way to fix it for your colleague to edit the `.git/config` file, find the `[remote]` entry that refers to the repo and fix the URL. There should be no need to re-fetch the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can view the URL used for the BitBucket repo by typing

```
git remote -v
```

This most likely will show that your colleague cloned has a remote that specifies your user name. The easiest way to fix this is to remove the user name from the url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/myself/my-repo.git
```

Now when they push/pull/fetch/etc, git will ask for both a user name and a url.

If your colleague doesn't want to type the user name each time, then they can instead do

```
git remote set-url origin https://colleague@bitbucket.org/myself/my-repo.git
```

If you are annoyed by always typing a username and password, I suggest setting up an SSH key and uploading the public key to BitBucket. The BitBucket docs explain how to do this. SSH is very convenient and provides secure access to your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

He needs to use the URL `https://mycolleague@bitbucket.org/myself/my-repo.git` to clone the repo -- note it has his username in one place and yours in another.